# Can power attack be used with bows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can power attack be used with composite bows?
The composite bow adds the  Strength modifier to damage (instead of the Dexterity modifier) so "power attack" maybe can be used too.

Comment: @user56480 Please put answers as answers along with their full support (rules, etc.) :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No.

> You can choose to take a –1 penalty on all **melee** attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a +2 bonus on all **melee** damage rolls.

<sup>([Power Attack feat description](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat/), **emphasis** mine)</sup>

Power Attack says melee, which means it doesn’t apply to ranged attacks. Technically, you can **use** Power Attack before making ranged attacks, but it won’t do anything—you’ll take no penalty to your attack roll and gain no bonus to your damage roll.

The feat you are looking for is [Deadly Aim](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat/). It works the same way, but it requires Dexterity instead of Strength, and there is no bonus for using two hands.

Comment: Pointing out Deadly Aim makes your answer superior to mine. I answered the question, not the issue.

Answer (score 9):

No.

The reason for this comes from the [feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat/) itself.

> You can choose to take a –1 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a +2 bonus on all melee damage rolls.

Note that it calls out *melee*. This means that unless you use the bow as an improvised weapon to hit someone next to you, it performs a ranged attack.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I wasnt aware that caps when used here would come out as shouty so thanks for the edit.